# Can iterator of `std::deque` go before its beginning

Tags: c++, iterator, deque

Is code like the following guaranteed to work, or is there undefined behavior?

```
#include <deque>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::deque<int> arr{1, 2, 3};
    auto it = arr.begin();
    --it;
    assert(it < arr.begin());
    assert(arr.begin() - it == 1);
    ++it;
    assert(*it == 1);
}
```

It makes an iterator to a `std::deque` go before `arr.begin()`, and then uses functions of the iterator (except for dereferencing it).

And if yes, is it also allowed for it to go after `arr.end()` (which is already one-part-the-end of the array), and is the same true for iterators `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc?

Comment: It's valid to have an iterator to one beyond the last element of the container, which is what `end` returns. As long as you don't attempt to dereference it, of course. But nothing else.

Comment: You may not do either of these things. You cannot get an iterator before `begin`, nor can you get an iterator after `end`. Your statement `assert(it < arr.begin());` is bogus. Do not use ordering comparisons for iterators. You may only use equality operators: `==` and `!=` and only if both iterators belong to the same object.

Comment: @paddy `<` is perfectly fine for RandomAccessIterators. Just in this case the `assert` can only be true if Undefined Behaviour happened, so compiler can do funny things with this code.

Comment: You're not allowed to do *anything* with an invalid iterator, and the decrement and increment themselves have undefined behaviour.